# Scale Image based on parent Image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an Two Images  a parrent Image (target) and a child Image (logo), I would like to scale the logo image to be 1/4th of the parent width, the height should adjust without losing the quality of the child

```
    resizeWaterMark(config) {
            return (target, logo) => {
                var context = target.getContext('2d');
                context.save();

                context.globalAlpha = config.opacity / 100;
                var img = new Image();

                //Define image ratio
                var ratio = logo.width / logo.height;

                let maxWidth = target.width / 4;
                let maxHeight = (target.width / 4) * ratio;

                img.width = maxWidth;
                img.height = maxHeight;

                img.onload = function () {
                    ctx.drawImage(img);
                };

                img.src = URL.create;

                let { x, y } = this.getWaterMarkPositionXY(target, img, config);
                context.drawImage(logo, x, y, img.width, img.height);
                context.restore();
                return target;
            };
        }
```

this is the logo
[image: The result i got widht is fine but height it not]

this is the result i get [image]

Comment: No, it's not a [MRE]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because various parts are missing to make it run with the code you provided. For example: Where is `getWaterMarkPositionXY` defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `object-fit` CSS property to scale the logo image to 1/4th of the parent width, and the height will adjust automatically without losing the quality of the image.

Read more about abject fit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: I would like to use JAVASCRIPT not css

Answer (score 0):

When you DIVIDE to scale images in canvas, you should always round-off the values like below.

You can’t have fractions for the size of the canvas since the pixel is a whole 1px in size!

Also, you don't need to create unnecessary variables like maxWidth.

Anyways, to cut a long story short replace all this:

```
//Define image ratio
  var ratio = logo.width / logo.height;

  let maxWidth = target.width / 4;
  let maxHeight = (target.width / 4) * ratio;

  img.width = maxWidth;
  img.height = maxHeight;
```

...with just this:

```
img.width = Math.round(target.width/4);

img.height = Math.round(target.height/4);
```

**NB**: You had *target.width* two times!